# Has anyone had success with large image, translation/animation on Chromecast?

Tags: chromecast

I've attempted several different css animations to move a large image up and down on the screen while I have music playing. I haven't found any variation on speed, distance translated, etc that results in a smooth transition.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm interested to know what the factors are in animation smoothness...

Comment: Ed, see below. Also I think smoothness has to do with what exactly you're trying to animate. For example something like an overlay for play/pause which is ~80px x 80px semi-transparent square you can use a css transition on the opacity. If the animation is about .25s then you should be okay.

Where I've experienced issues is with slowly moving a 1000x600px image slowly accross the screen.

Comment: Ok - I had similar experience. Animating text across the screen with a CSS transition was no problem at all. Use a 1080p image instead and you get a huge amount of tearing.

Comment: I'd be interested in an answer to this question as well.  I understand that Chromecast isn't incredibly beefy for this type of operation, but I'm wondering how Google did it themselves for their image gallery app that transitions between pictures when there aren't any apps running?

Comment: I'm also struggling to find a solution to this problem. My application requires to move 100 or so divs in a scrolling like fashion, updated at least 25fps (40ms). I've tried translateX, style.left, element.offset and all have similarly poor results. I've also tried using RequestAnimationFrame over setInterval to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Events in the Timeline panel of the Chromecast Chrome debugger, what you'll find is that any Paint to a reasonable amount of the screen takes about 100ms. Yes, 1/10 of a second! This makes any kind of animation (CSS, JQuery, etc.) very tricky and often jumpy.

For the movement of elements, I haven't seen any difference in CSS animation performance vs. JQuery animation() performance. I expect because the awful Paint times hide any differences.

One would have thought that Google would have used some of that great video hardware to improve the Chromecast browser paint performance, but this type of Chromecast app does not appear to be one of their uses cases.

Comment: Here's some more info. Not surprisingly certain CSS has significant negative impact on paint times. For example, removing `box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.1);` from the item I was animating dropped paint times by roughly 40% and increased apparent animation smoothness. I wound assume anything that modifies the underlying background (in this case an alpha shadow) should be used with care or not at all.

Comment: I also found similar results. When I tested with a full blown html5 canvas animation of snowflakes similar to [link](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/html5-canvas-snow-effect)[link]. I found that I could get a maximum of 3.5 frames per second. 

In another case, I was able to animate the opacity using 
'code'-webkit-transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out;'code'. .35s was pretty much the maximum length with having much better results.

I'm curious to try an move an image every 100ms to give it a sort of ken burns effect as if panning across the screen. My only concern is unexpected repaints

Comment: @FinnTheHuman Very valuable info! Indeed `box-shadow` is a performance killer on Chromecast. I believe the same goes for `text-shadow`. The tiny GPU certainly has to struggle when dealing with (I assume) off-screen buffers. Did you find some other culprits to be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

I'm developing a chromecast application where I have a very large, absolute-positioned DIV that I'm animating on and off of the screen.  It has a pretty complicated layout in it with html, css and images, even animated GIFs.  However, as long as I make sure there are no reflows while the animation is performing, I've gotten good performance by using `transform: translate()` CSS to control it's position.  Previously, I was modifying the `top` CSS property, but the performance was pitiful.

For an example to illustrate, here's some HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        ... Main content ...
    </div>
    <div id="overlay">
        ... Overlay content here ...
    </div>
</body>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 1180px;
    height: 670px;
    transition: all 1s;
    transform: rotate(-2deg) translateY(750px);
}

#overlay.active {
    transform: rotate(-2deg) translateY(0);
}
```

With this, all I do in my javascript is toggle the `active` class on and off to cause the overlay to show and hide itself.  I can't get the timeline debugger to work with the remote chromecast, so I don't know exactly what the FPS is, but it objectively feels like at least 30fps.  It definitely seems smooth.  I hope that helps.

Comment: I got the timeline debugger working, and my animation-heavy page went from ~3fps to ~15fps when I replaced animated `top` / `left` / `right` / `bottom` with `transform` :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a Chromecast device

- has limited resources (both CPU and memory)
- has a stripped-down version of chrome

As a result, you won't be able to do many fancy transitions/translations that you are otherwise able to do on a desktop or the performance (how smooth it is) is not going to be what you would like it to be, more so if you are playing a media concurrently.

Comment: I realize and completely understand the Chromecast has severe limitations, that being said your response is utterly useless. On several occasions I've found that changing timing as well as type of CSS animation greatly enhances performance.

For example if you fade-out and in based on opacity under .25s the animation feels pretty smooth. I've looked at the code for how the Chromecast team is doing animations and sometimes they go to great lengths to use 100+ images to animate something.

It's not possible is an unacceptable answer when people at Google/ on your team are making it happen.

Comment: If you are looking for a general recipe to tell you use these parameters and such, you wont be getting that since there is no such thing.You might be able to play with different parameters to improve the result in your case, but those tweaks are limited to the case at hand and cannot be generalized to all cases. All of this is caused by the limitations of the hardware. You are welcome to dive deep into the particular scenario that you have and see how you can improve what you are getting but the general answer to your question remains the same: you cannot expect fancy transitions in general.