# Chromecast Custom Receiver dropping frames

Tags: css-transitions, google-cast, custom-receiver

I'm creating a custom receiver app for the Chromecast.  I'm using some basic CSS transitions such moving an image from one point on the screen to another.  The transitions are extremely jittery.

Is there anything I can do to make these transitions better?

Answer (score 0):

Since the chromecast is not very powerful, it is likely that transitions will tend to be jittery. Supposedly, you can tweak some parameters, depending on the animation, and it will help smooth it out a little. You might be able to find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368667/has-anyone-had-success-with-large-image-translation-animation-on-chromecast).